# Renderizar un JSON en una tabla bootstrap Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, api, djangorestframework

Tengo un modelo al cual he llamado `Empleado` el cual tiene una llave foránea hacia un modelo `Direccion` para conservar un histórico de las direcciones del empleado.

Serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from models import Empleado, Direccion


class DireccionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Direccion
        fields = ('id', 'pais', 'estado', 'municipio', 'ciudad', 'calle', 'colonia', 'numero_interior',
              'numero_exterior', 'codigo_postal', 'datos_adicionales')


class EmpleadoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    direccion = DireccionSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Empleado
        fields = ('id', 'nombre', 'apellido_paterno', 'apellido_materno', 'fecha_nacimiento', 'rfc', 'curp',
              'direccion')
```

Por ahora estoy mostrando los registros de `Empleado` en una tabla con el siguiente ciclo:

```
{% for empleado in object_list %}
<tr>
     <td> {{ empleado.id }}</td>
     <td> {{ empleado.nombre }} </td>
     <td> {{ empleado.apellido_paterno }} </td>
     <td> {{ empleado.apellido_materno }} </td>
     <td> {{ empleado.fecha_nacimiento|date:"Y-m-d" }} </td>
     <td> {{ empleado.curp }} </td>
     <td> {{ empleado.rfc }} </td>

     <td>
     {{ empleado.direccion.get_full_information|truncatechars:30 }}
     </td>

 </tr>

{% endfor %}
```

Construí la siguiente vista:

```
class EmpleadosListApi(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = EmpleadoSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Empleado.objects.filter(activo=1).order_by('id')
```

Y quiero renderizar el JSON en la tabla en lugar de usar los tags de Django. Intenté hacerlo con un ejemplo que encontré en Internet usando el atributo `data-field` de Bootstrap pero no se realizar lo que requiero y no he encontrado de qué manera hacerla. Es la primera vez que trabajo con APIS, soy bastante nueva.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap por si mismo no acepta esas propiedades, pero puedes usar la [librería bootstrap tables](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/getting-started/), es decir, necesitas agregar las referencias a su CSS y JS, además de invocarlo según necesites

Por ejemplo desde un [json directo](http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/13/) (desde la [documentación oficial](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/es/examples/)) donde `data-field` es el nombre del elemento en json.

Es importante notar que se genera con el siguiente código:

```
$(function () {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
       data: data
    });
});
```

Donde (con Jquery) al cargarse la página se selecciona el elemento HTML de la tabla mediante el `id` y se aplica el json que esta en la variable `data` con el método `bootstrapTable`

En tu caso tendrías que aplicarlo cuando obtengas la información de tu json (asumo que en el success de tu ajax) y no olvides convertirlo a un objeto javascript ya que muy probablemente lo obtengas como texto

Comment: Gracias, por lo pronto lo solucioné de una manera algo rústica, voy a aplicar tu respuesta a ver como me va. Acabo de responder mi propia pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias, lo hice llamando los items del JSON e inyectado los atributos a las etiquetas `<td>`, espero que a alguien le sirva.

```
<script>
$(document).on('ready',function(){
    $.ajax({url: "{% url 'empleados:empleados_list_api' %}",
        data:{lista: 'empleados'},
        dataType:"json",
        type:"GET"
    }).done(function(data){

        $.each(data, function(index, item){

            var direccion = '';
            var fdireccion = '';
            if (item.direccion.calle.length != 0)direccion += item.direccion.calle;
            if (item.direccion.numero_interior.length != 0)direccion += ' No. Int. ' + item.direccion.numero_interior;
            if (item.direccion.numero_interior.length != 0 && item.direccion.numero_exterior.length != 0)direccion += ' ,';
            if (item.direccion.numero_exterior.length != 0)direccion += ' No. Ext. ' + item.direccion.numero_exterior;
            if (item.direccion.colonia.length != 0)direccion += ', Colonia ' + item.direccion.colonia;
            if (item.direccion.codigo_postal.length != 0)direccion += ', C.P. ' + item.direccion.codigo_postal;
            if (item.direccion.ciudad.length != 0)direccion += ', ' + item.direccion.ciudad;
            if (item.direccion.municipio.length != 0)direccion += ', ' + item.direccion.municipio;
            if (item.direccion.estado.length != 0)direccion += ', ' + item.direccion.estado;
            if (item.direccion.pais.length != 0)direccion += ', ' + item.direccion.pais;
            if (direccion.length>30)fdireccion = $.trim(direccion).substring(0, 30).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "...";
            else fdireccion=direccion;
            var $tr = $('<tr>').append(
                    $('<td>').text(item.id),
                    $('<td>').text(item.nombre),
                    $('<td>').attr({'class':'hidden-xs','style':'width: 15%;'}).text(item.apellido_paterno),
                    $('<td>').attr({'class':'hidden-xs','style':'width: 15%;'}).text(item.apellido_materno),
                    $('<td>').attr({'class':'hidden-xs','style':'width: 15%;'}).text(item.fecha_nacimiento),
                    $('<td>').attr({'class':'hidden-xs','style':'width: 15%;'}).text(item.curp),
                    $('<td>').attr({'class':'hidden-xs','style':'width: 15%;'}).text(item.rfc),
                    $('<td>').attr({'class':'hidden-xs','style':'width: 15%;','data-toggle':'tooltip','title':''+direccion}).text(fdireccion),
                    $('<td>').attr('class','text-center').append(
                            $('<div>').attr('class','btn-group').append(
                                $('<a>').attr(
                                        {   'class':'btn btn-xs btn-default',
                                            'type':'button',
                                            'data-toggle':'tooltip',
                                            'title':'Editar Empleado'
                                        }
                                ).append(
                                        $('<i>').attr('class','fa fa-pencil')).data('id',item.id).click(function(){
                                    var id = $(this).data('id');
                                    window.location = 'edit/'+item.id;
                                }),
                                $('<a>').attr(
                                        {   'class':'btn btn-xs btn-default',
                                            'type':'button',
                                            'data-toggle':'tooltip',
                                            'title':'Eliminar Empleado'
                                        }
                                ).append(
                                        $('<i>').attr('class','fa fa-times')).data('id',item.id).click(function(){
                                    var id = $(this).data('id');
                                    window.location = 'delete/'+item.id;
                                })
                            ))
            ).appendTo('#tabla_lista_empleados');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```